# ADT Can't find the tools directory

Tags: android, debugging, adt

Ok, everything was working fine, I had the ADT 0.9 installed under eclipse Galileo. But then I just tryied to install the Honeycomb preview SDK and for that I was prompted to install the ADT 9.0.

The problem is that somehow my tools folder was erased! and apparently it has now been renamed as platform-tools. But whenever I go to Preferences->Android and put the folder where my SDK is, eclipse keeps complaining about the missing tools directory.

What can I do?

UPDATE: The problem was a mix of bad ADT installation and an expired debug key. For more info about how dealing with the expired debug key just take a look at: http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/11/tip-dealing-with-expired-debug.html

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer, so it could be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart your workbench and go to Help -> Check for updates.  The many of the tools were officially moved from $sdk_root/tools to $sdk_root/platform-tools and the only reason you would be receiving an error would be that you have an old version of ADT.

You can check the version of ADT by going to Help -> About Eclipse SDK.  My guess is that either the update failed or after the update you didn't restart the work bench.  If neither of these cases is true, i would recommend uninstalling the SDKs and redownloading.

Comment: Well.. it turned out that was ONE of my problems. Apparently the ADT instalation went wrong and just reinstalling it would have solved my problem. The other problem was that my debug certificate expired just yesterday!! what are the odds that a problem that should appear only once a year happens just when I update my SDK and ADT??! (making me believe that the problem's origin was the update). But thanks for the advice anyway. If anyone is interested in the latter problem, here's the link that helped me on that: http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/11/tip-dealing-with-expired-debug.html